# Returning jQuery Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-post

I wish to use the jQuery.post class to return (not alert) the response within a function.

**The following gives an alert with the appropriate value:**

```
function test_func() {
    $.post("test.php", { cmd: "testing" }, function (data) { alert(data); })
}
```

(displays alert with appropriate value)

**I tried the following:**

```
function test_func() {
    return $.post("test.php", { cmd: "testing" }, function (data) { return data; })
}
```

(returned object)

```
function test_func() {
    var tmp;
    $.post("test.php", { cmd: "testing" }, function (data) { tmp=data; })
    return tmp;
}
```

(returned undefined)

```
var tmp;

function setTmp(n) {
    tmp=n;
}

function test_func() {
    t=$.post("test.php", { cmd: "testing" }, function (data) { setTmp(data); })
}
```

(returned undefined)

```
function test_func() {
    t=$.post("test.php", { cmd: "testing" })
    return t.responseText;
}
```

(returned undefined)

**So what's the deal? How can I make "test_func()" return the data response text?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deal is ajax is asynchronous one possible solution is to set it as sync like

```
$.ajaxSetup({
async:false
});
```

and then

```
function test_func() {
var temp;
    t=$.post("test.php", { cmd: "testing" })
    return t.responseText;
}
```

the answer is only to make your current setup work else there are better ways to deal with it

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the help. This is enlightening. Implemented and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Being an asynchronous request, you aren't able to get a response as soon as you call the function. Instead, the `function` that you pass to `$.post` is intended to be a callback that will perform some action as soon as the response is complete. Consider the following:

```
function myCallback(response) {
  // do something with `response`...
}

function test_func() {
  $.post("test.php", { cmd: "testing" }, myCallback)
}
```

Instead of directly returning a response, you can instead manipulate it as needed in the `myCallback` function.